# Q: Cannot find Kotlin kernel in Jupyter notebook

Tags: kotlin, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to use the Kotlin kernel after installing both it and Jupyter using `pip3`.
I have also tried the `fix-kernelspec-location` script, as mentioned in the README on the Kotlin Jupyter kernel repo https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-jupyter:

```
% python -m kotlin_kernel fix-kernelspec-location
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named kotlin_kernel
% python3 -m kotlin_kernel fix-kernelspec-location
```

To reproduce the error:

1. I start a Jupyter session using `jupyter lab`.
2. I am still only able to use the Python3 kernel, as shown in the screenshot below:
   [image: Screenshot 2021-05-27 at 1 16 34 PM]

Any help is appreciated! I'm fairly new to setting up Python environments and have gotten myself confused with Anaconda, virtual environments and the like before, so I'm opting to keep things simple using just `pip3` for now.

Here's more explanation of my installation process:
While installing Jupyter using `pip3 install jupyter`, I encountered the following error at the end:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.d/widgetsnbextension.json'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Googling this error did not provide any hints.
I then ran `pip3 install jupyterlab`. At this point, trying `jupyter lab` produced this error: `'ExtensionManager' object has no attribute '_extensions'`, which I surmise is linked to this issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10228
I tried the fix on that page, i.e. `jupyter server extension disable nbclassic`.
Next, I uninstalled and reinstalled the Kotlin kernel using `pip3 uninstall kotlin-jupyter-kernel` followed by `pip3 install kotlin-jupyter-kernel`.
Below is the output:

```
Collecting kotlin-jupyter-kernel
  Downloading kotlin_jupyter_kernel-0.10.0.40-py3-none-any.whl (70.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 70.5 MB 9.4 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: kotlin-jupyter-kernel
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/kotlin'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I've also posted this question in an issue at the Kotlin kernel repository: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-jupyter/issues/268.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try install with sudo:

```
sudo pip3 install kotlin-jupyter-kernel
sudo python3 -m kotlin_kernel fix-kernelspec-location
```